# GEOS and Shapely installation on Windows

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, shapely

When trying to install Shapely on my Windows 64bit computer, I cannot get the GEOS library to work.

So far, I have run the OSGeo4W installer from which I installed GDAL (I believe the geos library is included in that package). After that, I checked and I have geos_c.dll on my `C:\OSGeo4W\bin` directory, but either I have missed some configuration steps or the library does not work.

I need Shapely to work, so I also ran `pip install shapely` after  installing GDAL, and it apparently worked (although it could not find the C library for GEOS).

In my code, I can import Shapely, but when I try to use it, I get an error telling me `"geos.dll"` is not found.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Uninstall shapely and try to install it from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). Hope it helps. It worked for me.

Comment: This did it.  I actually used the same page to download Numpy for an unrelated library, but I didn't see shapely there.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This is AFAIK, the only place you can get a windows installer for shapely.

Comment: just a note for python noobies like myself: the -cpXX- refers to your python version.  As of this writing, current versions would be cp27 or cp35.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem but now everything is working perfectly. You can download the shapely package (in wheel package) from the link shared by Mario Miler ([link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely))
Choose you package according to your windows and python version. Download the file, it has .whl extension. It is file format for python Wheel package.

Go to cmd and enter:

```
pip install wheel
```

Then cd to the folder where you have downloaded and enter

```
pip install 'your_package_full_name'.whl
```

Comment: where do you find the .whl file? I used the link you give to download shapely but the downloaded file is a zip file, which contains two folders, neither of which seems to contain a .whl file. There is a file called WHEEL with no extension but it isn't something I can run with pip.

Comment: the file you download from the [link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) _is_ the `.whl` file. Perhaps you have file extensions hidden in Windows? Open a Windows command prompt in your download folder and you will see the `.whl` extension. And now you can run the `pip` command :-)

Answer (score 3):

The geos_c.dll needs to be in your `%PATH%`. Per default, OSGeo4W installs directly under C:. If you did that, add `C:\OSGeo4W64\bin` to your `%PATH%` : right-click on "This PC"->Advanced System Settings->Environment Varialbes. Setting it only for or system-wide will both work - take your pick. Restart your console and `conda install shapely` should work.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2020, the recommended method to install Shapely (with it's own GEOS) is simply:

```
pip install shapely
```

(you may need `--upgrade` to get at least version 1.7.0, when Windows binary wheels were supported)

Comment: Even using the latest shapely it does not work for me. When I run the install I get the error: ``FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'geos_c.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.``

Answer (score 1):

Given that you use Conda, a `conda` installation also works and in the easiest way. Simply try

`conda install shapely`

It will download and install the correct shapely and geos.

(Posting this, as the wheel from [Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) did not work either.)